# Chartkickのサイズを変更できないです。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

#### 前提・実現したいこと

**chartkick**のサイズを変更したいです。
正規の方法でサイズを変更を試みましたが、変更できなかったのでご相談させていただきます。

#### 該当のソースコード

少し複雑な流れですが、、、
以下の流れで**chartkick**を表示しています。

【users/show】

```
<div>
  <div>
   ・
   ・
   ・
   <span class="show-profile-overall">
    <%= render 'users_show/show_profile'%>
   </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

【users_show/_show_profile.html.erb】

```
<section class="user-show-content">
  ・
  ・
  ・
</section>
 <%= render 'users_show/show_user_data' %>
```

【users_show/_show_user_data.html.erb】

```
<div class="line-chart", id="cont6"><%= line_chart @chart_data, width: "500px" %></div>
```

このようにコードを記述してもまったく大きさに関して反応がありません。
おそらくなどの構造は関係ないとは思うのですが、一応載せました…

#### 試したこと

①**line_chart**に**id**を挿入し、cssで装飾を試みましたができませんでした。
②**class="line-chart"**でサイズ変更を試みましたができませんでした。

マルチポスト
[テラテイル](https://teratail.com/questions/56757?modal=q-comp)

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。

`<div>`を外したところサイズを変更をすることができました。
最近、こういうの多いので気を付けます(*´Д｀)！！！

すみませんでした。

【bofore】

```
<div class="line-chart", id="cont6"><%= line_chart @chart_data, width: "500px" %></div>
```

【after】

```
<%= line_chart @chart_data, id: "cont6", width: "500px" %>
```